# Upgrade or replace a Wubi installation?

Tags: windows-7, wubi

I've got Windows 7 with Wubi 11.10 installed. I would like to upgrade to 12.04 but I'm not sure what the best path would be.

I'm not skilled enough to use Ubuntu all the time, and my iPhone requires me to run some Windows version for the damn iTunes software. I would love to run Windows XP but I can't figure out how to install it via USB -- my computer has no cd drive.

I'd like to run Windows XP and Wubi 12.04 on top of that. Or, perhaps, Ubuntu 12.04 natively and Windows XP alongside of that. So I guess I have 2 questions:

1. (lazy) **Should I upgrade my Wubi from inside Ubuntu, or should I remove Wubi 11.10 from within Windows and install a brand new Wubi 12.04?**
2. (proper) **How can I install Windows XP and Ubuntu 12.04 alongside each other?**

*Update: I am going to create a separate question post about the above #2 question... I realize it's wrong to ask two questions in one post when they are that different.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not normally link to a page that was not an ubuntu wiki or information source as they often go missing.

However this is by the user on the forum who deals with an enormous amount of wubi threads.

http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.ca/2012/04/how-to-upgrade-wubi-install.html

Summary:

- Wait a while for latest fixes to exist.
- Do a backup.
- Do a full backup.
- Really. Do a complete backup!!
- Ensure there's at least 3GB free space. Even more is even better.
- Consider removing any PPA's first (reinstall them later).
- Let Ubuntu upgrade itself.

This *usually* works. You did make a backup, right?

Answer (score 1):

> Should I upgrade my Wubi from inside Ubuntu, or should I remove Wubi 11.10 from within Windows and install a brand new Wubi 12.04?

- **Fresh WUBI Install is recommended...** if you haven't used 11.10 a lot and don't really have programs/settings you can't easily recreate, just backup your home directory to a USB, uninstall the old and install the new 12.04.
- **Update from 11.10 will also work...** but may be a problem if your Wubi drive is small (4-6 GB or so).

Comment: I am working a lot in Wubi, and the Wubi drive is 30GB. It sounds like there's no problem in just upgrading it inside Wubi then.

Comment: No, you will have no problems then - plenty of space.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to uninstall WUBI from  Windows and do a clean install of Ubuntu. This will be least buggy.